# GITHUB - Auto Re-base of branches when commit happens on current branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Requirement is whenever commit happens on current branch then sub branches or set of branches need to be auto re-based with current branch changes.

I can have a script or service to do this activity. My question is regarding how/where can I maintain destination branches those need to be re-based.

One option would be maintaining relation of Source and Destination branches in config file. Maintenance is involved in this approach, branch details need to be updated whenever branch is added/removed.

I am looking for optimal solution/industry standard way of doing this activity.

Comment: What happens if there's a conflict?

Comment: If conflict occurs then user would resolve it manually

Comment: It sounds like you've decided to use a distributed version control system but also pretend it is a centralized version control system and enforce a linear history. At some point you're probably going to realize that embracing the distributed functionality and how it works is going to be far less stressful and errorprone than you're expecting.

Comment: I am rephrasing my subject, auto re-base of open branches when commit happens on Master. Is it standard way to use Git?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an "industry standard" solution for this, because this is not a standard way to use git.

If you must do this for some reason, you would make the command a git hook (https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

If you want to track changes you make to the hooks, you should store the hook files in a separate repository.